# Chaining resource asynchronous call using promise that depend on previous resource call

Tags: angularjs, chaining, angular-promise, ngresource

I have a problem chaining resource calls that depends on previous variables, below are the code. The test variable returns an object that contain an authorityId properties that i wanted to use to call another resource and add the return value to the object return by test. It seems i can't get it to work with defer properly, please suggest a proper way to this and explain it so that i can fully grasp the concept.

```
test will return {   
Key : [{ properties: somethingSomething, properties2: somethingSomething, 
         properties3:somethingSomething}]
}



(function (angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('module.userManagement')
    .factory('userService', ['userCtrlService','authoritiesService','$q',function     (userCtrlService,authoritiesService,$q) {

        var test = $q.all({'getAdminRole' : authoritiesService.getAdministrator().$promise,'getUserRole': authoritiesService.getUserRole().$promise}).then(function(results){
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var resourceList = [];
                        angular.forEach(results,function(value,key){
                           value.$promise.then(function(response){
                               angular.forEach(response, function(v,k){
                                  resourceList.push(v);
                               });
                           });
                        });
                       deferred.resolve(resourceList);
                       return deferred.promise;
                    });

        console.log('USER SERVICE!');

 test.then(function(response){
          var authorityList = {};
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          angular.forEach(response, function(resValue,key){
            authoritiesService.getAuthenticationAssignment({id:resValue.authorityId}).$promise.then(function(response){
                var className = {};
                if(response[resValue.authorityId][0]) {
                    className['className'] = response[resValue.authorityId][0].className;
                    className['singular'] = response[resValue.authorityId][0].singular;
                }
               authorityList[resValue.name] = [{'description': resValue.description, 'authorityId': resValue.authorityId, 'category': resValue.authorityCategoryName, 'level':className}];
            });
          });
          deferred.resolve(authorityList);

          console.log(authorityList);
        });
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises) tutorial.

Comment: Use array method or then. Something like service.get1().then().then().then()